# How do I loop through a file and remove all lines that fit the condition?

Tags: python

I have a huge file. I've tried with other software, and it didn't work. So I want to make a custom script.
However, I just cannot work it out myself.

I want to delete every line in a file with the following condition: `if "[" in line:`
File in question is a .txt file with about 14,000,000 lines. I would prefer something fast.

I've tried other similar functions on this page, but I couldn't find any that would fit my requirements.

Comment: are you using linux ?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deleting, you can pretty easily make a copy of the file with only the desired records.

```
in_file_path = 'xxxx'
out_file_path = 'yyyy'

with open(in_file_path, 'r') as fh_in:
    with open(out_file_path, 'w') as fh_out:
        for line in fh_in:
            if not '[' in line:
                fh_out.write(line)
```

If you want to go even faster, you can read and write in binary mode and check for `b'['` in the line.

Comment: I'm having this error: return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 359: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I fixed it by adding the encoding="utf-8" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the readline method of the file object inside a while loop. So while you are in the loop get all lines that do not fit the if condition and store into into a data structure.

Later open a new file and write th entire structure to the new file

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is a simple read and write of a file:

```
with open("sample_file.txt", "r") as reader:
    new_file = []
    for line in reader:
        if "[" not in line:
            new_file.append(line)
    with open("new_file.txt", "w+") as writer:
        writer.writelines(new_file)
```